# chef database cookbook deprecated

Tags: chef

I frequently use chef database cookbook and it is being deprecated doesn't receive any updates. They even disabled issues on the github so it is not possible to check if any issues I encounter have been discussed and possible solutions were proposed. The deprecation notice says that functionality of this cookbook is supposed to be moved to individual database cookbooks but this still isn't implemented, at least for MySQL. Is there any alternatives to this cookbook or I'm just stuck with creating another fork alongside hundreds of others?

Comment: A better place to discuss it would chef's slack, specially the brigade channel with is an effort to Take over maintenance of old cookbooks (link is in the community tab of https://learn.chef.io

Comment: I can't comment so... Man i really wish there was an answer. At least one I could read since anything that happened in Slack is lost for the rest of the world defeating the entire purpose of this site :(

Comment: @Tensibai I have to disagree, I'm with NecLimDul on this one - slack is ephemeral, those discussions will dissapear after a short while.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Slack is all but ephemeral, all messages are archived and publicly searchable... And as any answer to this can change quickly asking again on a chat system is far better than an outdated fixed post no one will maintain.

Comment: @NecLimDul FYI there's no rule to prevent asking a question already asked on Slack, nothing is lost on slack neither, that's the whole purpose of the move from IRC to slack: https://chefcommunity.slackarchive.io/general/page-100

Comment: @Tensibai I stand corrected. Thx.

Comment: @Dan no worries :) Chef community support team has, for reasons, a certain reluctance about q/a format, and I have to agree as a bunch of my answers about chef on SO are outdated or superseded with a better way now.

Comment: @Tensibai, your link to slackarchive.io is dead.

Comment: @AlexD 4 years latter that's a bit less true about the ephemeral part, but the communication FAQ is [here now](https://github.com/chef/chef-oss-practices/blob/master/communication/communication-faq.md#communication-faqs)  and the point stand, 80% of my answers around Chef are still valid if you're on a 4 years old version of Chef, not on recent versions, maintaining them with each major (every year) is a nightmare, that was the reason to abandon a wiki based documentation too and show more an more true.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for is a chef cookbook to manage MySQL, I would recommend checking [this](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql) It is an officially maintained cookbook. Keep in mind that:

> This cookbook is concerned with the "MySQL Community Server", particularly those shipped with F/OSS Unix and Linux distributions. It does not address forks or value-added repackaged MySQL distributions like MariaDB or Percona.

I hope this could help.

Comment: This 'mysql' cookbook doesn't provide functionality of 'database' cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

[MariaDB cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mariadb) added support for `mariadb_database` and `mariadb_user` resources in the version 1.5.4 released on May 25 2018.